# python pandas deduplication with complex criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe below:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 1, 8, 9], 'cluster': [7, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 7, 8, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.sort_values('cluster')
```

I want to keep ALL the rows
if there is the same cluster but different id AND keep every row from that cluster
even if it is the same id since there was a different id AT LEAST once within that cluster.
The code I have been using to achieve this is the following below, BUT, the only problem
with this is it drops too many rows for what I am looking for.

```
df = (df.assign(counts=df.count(axis=1))
   .sort_values(['id', 'counts'])
   .drop_duplicates(['id','cluster'], keep='last')
   .drop('counts', axis=1))
```

The output dataframe I am expecting that the code above does not do
would drop rows at
dataframe index 1, 5, 0, and 6 but leave dataframe indexes 2, 3, 4, 7, and 8.  Essentially
resulting in what the code below produces:

```
df = df.loc[[2, 3, 4, 7, 8]]
```

I have looked at many deduplication pandas posts on stack overflow but have yet to find this
scenario.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can do this with a single boolean. using `.groupby().nunique()`

```
con1 = df.groupby('cluster')['id'].nunique() > 1

#of these we only want the True indexes.

cluster
2    False
3     True
6    False
7    False
8     True


df.loc[(df['cluster'].isin(con1[con1].index))]

   id  cluster
2   3        3
3   4        3
4   4        3
7   8        8
8   9        8
```